# PHP variable (global) seems to become NULL in next block of code

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am using PHP to:

1. Open a connection to a MySQL database.
2. Receive some data from a website, & insert this data into a table in the DB.
3. Get the value of the most recent auto-incremented primary key from that table, & store that value in a variable.
4. Take that value and, along with other data, insert it into another table in the same DB.

But, after I get the value of the most recent id and put it into a variable (i.e. when I am done with step 3 and ready for step 4), my variable seems to become NULL.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (authentication succeeds)
  {
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    die($conn->connect_error);
    }
  if (!empty($_POST['SomeData']))
    {
    $sql = 'valid SQL statement';
    if ($conn->query($sql) !== TRUE)
      {
      echo $conn->error;
      } else {
             $LastID = $conn->insert_id;
             echo 'Checkpoint A: $LastID type is ' . gettype($LastID) . ' and value is ' . $LastID . '   ';
             }
    }
  echo 'Checkpoint B: $LastID type is ' . gettype($LastID) . ' and value is ' . $LastID . '   ';
  if (!empty($_POST['OtherData']))
    {
    echo 'Checkpoint C: $LastID type is ' . gettype($LastID) . ' and value is ' . $LastID . '   ';
    }
  }
?>
```

At Checkpoint A and Checkpoint B, $LastID is an integer, but at Checkpoint C, $LastID is NULL.  ... Why?

Comment: You cannot refer to a variable before its declaration.

You can declare variables in several different places:

 `1. In a class body as class fields. Variables declared here are
    referred to as class-level variables.
 2. As parameters of a method or constructor.
 3. In a method's body or a constructor's body.
 4. Within a statement block, such as inside a while or for block.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to a variable before its declaration. You can declare variables in several different places:

1. In a class body as class fields. Variables declared here are referred to as class-level variables.
2. As parameters of a method or constructor.
3. In a method's body or a constructor's body.
4. Within a statement block, such as inside a while or for block.

you can fix that by adding `$LastID = null` before or after `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: Ohh... I just realized that I declared `$LastID` within the first conditional.  So if the script finishes, garbage collects, and then starts over again, and this time the first condition evaluates to `FALSE`, then `$LastID` won't have been declared.  ... It helps to look at things fresh in the morning, haha.

Answer (score 0):

**put your data or variable whatever you want globally in $GLOBALS  variable.
for example:**

```
$GLOBALS =$conn;
```

Comment: Well, this code...  `$myVar = 99;
$GLOBALS += $myVar;` ... threw an exception for "unsupported operand types"...